# Postgres role does not inherit permissions of superuser role via membership in that role

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

In the snippet below, the role `writer` is a member of a superuser role named `admin`. The `admin` role can insert rows into a table but the `writer` role cannot insert rows into the same table.  Why does the `writer` role not inherit permissions from the superuser role `admin`?

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_check_roles( id SERIAL NOT NULL );
CREATE ROLE admin SUPERUSER LOGIN;

-- Insert succeeds as the admin role.
SET ROLE admin;
INSERT INTO test_check_roles (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);

-- Insert fails as the writer role with:
--   ERROR:  permission denied for table test_check_roles
CREATE ROLE writer LOGIN INHERIT;
GRANT admin TO writer;
SET ROLE writer;
INSERT INTO test_check_roles (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

Based on the documentation below ([Postgres 12 - Role Membership](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/role-membership.html)), I expected `writer` to have all privileges of the `admin` user since the writer role has the INHERIT tag.

> Member roles that have the INHERIT attribute automatically have use of the privileges of roles of which they are members, including any privileges inherited by those roles.

#### Reproducible example

```
docker run --name pg-test -d --rm \
    --env POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust \
    -p 54321:5432 \
    postgres:12.2

psql -h localhost -p 54321 -U postgres -d postgres \
    -c "CREATE TABLE test_check_roles( id SERIAL NOT NULL )" \
    -c "CREATE ROLE admin SUPERUSER LOGIN" \
    -c "SET ROLE admin" \
    -c "INSERT INTO test_check_roles (id) VALUES (DEFAULT)" \
    -c "CREATE ROLE writer LOGIN INHERIT" \
    -c "GRANT admin TO writer" \
    -c "SET ROLE writer" \
    -c "INSERT INTO test_check_roles (id) VALUES (DEFAULT)"

docker stop pg-test
```

#### Related questions

- [Postgres role permission problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255645/postgres-role-permission-problem): Related to `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.
- [Why is a new user allowed to create a table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/why-is-a-new-user-allowed-to-create-a-table?rq=1) - Has a good answer describing that privileges aren't hierarchial.

#### Observations

If I run `CREATE TABLE` as the admin role instead of the postgres role, the example works. It seems the permission are somewhere lost between `postgres` owning the table, the `admin` having superuser, and `writer` being a member of admin. I don't follow why a table created by the `postgres` role is accessible by `admin` by not by `writer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUPERUSER doesn't inherit; it's an attribute of a role rather than a permission.

> The role attributes LOGIN, SUPERUSER, CREATEDB, and CREATEROLE can be thought of as special privileges, but they are never inherited as ordinary privileges on database objects are. You must actually SET ROLE to a specific role having one of these attributes in order to make use of the attribute.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html

Comment: To clarify my understanding: `admin` can access tables created by the `postgres` role because its SUPERUSER attribute bypasses permission checks. The `writer` role doesn't inherit that ability.  However, `writer` can access tables created by `admin` because table permissions are inherited.

Comment: Yes, but don't do it! `writer` will then be able to do everything `admin` can because you granted `admin` to `writer`.